# Excel FIND and keep text after a character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find

I have in a cell names like :

```
XXX XXX"CHAR(10)"YYY YYY"CHAR(10)"ZZZ ZZZ
```

The lines in the cell are separated by `CHAR(10)`, but I also have cell with just `WWW WWW` , so there is no `CHAR(10)` in that.

I am using a formula to delete everything after the first `CHAR(10)` and just keep the first line, but i need an upgrade to the formula to also copy the line if no `CHAR(10)` is found in the cell.

The formula so far is :

```
=LEFT(A1; FIND(CHAR(10);A1;1))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
=LEFT(A1; FIND(CHAR(10);A1 & CHAR(10);1))
```

if you want to copy the whole cell if there is no Char(10).

Or you could use e.g. IFERROR.